# boost::regex and tilde (~)

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

Please could you explain why given the following boost::regex pattern:

```
boost::regex re("/\\S+\\w");
```

`/index.html` is a match and `/~index.html` is not? 
RegexBuddy in Perl mode finds a match in both cases.

Could you suggest a pattern that would work? Thanks!!

P.S. The `\\w` at the end is needed in order to ignore the punctuation on the end of an URL like `/index.html.`.

**UPD: Sorry just tried to make a simple test program and it works there. I guess the problem might be in the code that calls regex_search. I need a bit more time to find this out.**

**UPD2: Indeed the problem was in my code. Please vote to close the question. Sorry for not researching enough before posting.**

Comment: I have not worked on boost!!!!. Is escaping character is really required for \S and \W   ?..?.     "\/\S+\w" This works for me in Perl

Comment: Boost is a c++ library and c++ string escaping is not as  weak as the perl. the \\S and \\w are correct.

Comment: I think as question asker you can close or delete the question yourself.